# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. AplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I calling GetSurveysAuditorByUserEmail method. This method connects to remote another DB and return records.

```
public SurveysService(ApplicationDbContext context) {
  _context = context;
}

public IList<Survey> GetSurveysAuditorByUserEmail(string email) {
  var idsSurveys = new List<string>( );
  var surveys = new List<Survey>( );
  try {
    using(IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connStringAudit)) {
      idsSurveys = db.Query<string>("Select (CONVERT(nvarchar(450), Id) + Funz) as IdRilievo From V_TemView Where Email = @email",
        new { email }).ToList( );

    }

    surveys = _context.Surveys.Where(o => idsSurveys.Contains(o.Id)).ToList( );
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    _logger.Write(e.Message);
  }

  return surveys;
}
```

On the line `surveys = _context.Surveys.Where(o => idsSurveys.Contains(o.Id)).ToList();` I get error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A
>   common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
>   from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
>   context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur is you
>   are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
>   using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
>   the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
>   instances. Object name: ‘ApplicationDbContext’.

**EDIT**:

I call this method in another class:

```
public async Task<List<IGrouping<int, Survey>>> GroupSurveyByIntervId(User user) {
  IList<Survey> surveys = new List<Survey>( );
  var statuses = _context.Statuses.ToList( );
  //var surv = _context.Surveys.ToList();

  var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

  surveys = _surveysService.GetSurveysAuditorByUserEmail(user.Email);

  var groupSurv = surveys.GroupBy(x => x.InterventionId).ToList( );
  return groupSurv;
}
```

**EDIT**

I inject ApplicationDbContext in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddIdentity<TrackingUser, TrackingRole>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
  })
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>( );
```

How can I solve? Thank you

Comment: How are you instantiating the method's parent class? Are you using `context` in another method?

Comment: Where and when do you dispose the ApplicationDbContext that gets passed in to the constructor of this class?

Comment: I updated question. 

I use DI in startup, than in every class i inject in constructor

Comment: You seem to have two overloads of `GetSurveysAuditorByUserEmail()`, one with a context parameter and one without. You're calling the former in the last-added code sample, but you showed us the latter. Please show the actual code that's actually throwing the exception. P.S. code belongs in the question, not in comments.

Comment: No, i updated code. I dont use _context params in method.

Comment: @StefanHansch Where and when do you dispose the ApplicationDbContext that gets passed in to the constructor of this class?

Comment: can you post the registerService part of your Db

Comment: @ Ed Plunkett:He should not dispose, Dependency container will take care of it.

Comment: also why are you trying to use a DbConnection when DbContext is already there

Comment: @CodeNameJack In that case, if he's disposing it, perhaps there's the bug.

Comment: I believe somethign is wrong in his app configuration too, Without seeing the full picture, we cant say. Framework is almost never wrong.

Comment: I updated question with my DI in Startup class

Comment: Configuration is correct. I have edited my answer. can you check once

Comment: I connect to remote DB and get records from View. After regarding this records I looking data in my local Db, in table Surveys.

Comment: Which version of ef core are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
surveys = _context.Surveys.Where(o => idsSurveys.Contains(o.Id)).ToList();
```

You are trying to use that outside the using block.
Do it like this

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connStringAudit))
{
    idsSurveys = db.Query<string>("Select (CONVERT(nvarchar(450), Id) + Funz) as IdRilievo From V_TemView Where Email = @email",
                      new { email }).ToList();
    surveys = _context.Surveys.Where(o => idsSurveys.Contains(o.Id)).ToList();
}
```

db is disposed outside this using block and so is the query object.

Few Clarifications: If you are using entity framework core, Do not using a separate dbconnection.
If you want to connect to two different databases, then use different DataContext.

Do not open Parellal Connection to same DB. It is forcing the existing connection to close.

in case it is the same Database and you are using code first migration,

In `DBContext` class add `DBSet<IdRilievo>` property and access it from the same context object.

Comment: How is `db` related to `context`? Given the code he produced, they are completely unrelated objects.

Comment: its not related to context, It is related to `idsSurveys` in idsSurveys.Contains(o.Id)).ToList();

Comment: @CodeNameJack `idsSurveys` was returned by ToList(), on the query, inside the `using`. Ordinarily, I would expect that to cause the query to execute inside the using block.

Comment: Is `db.Query` a EF thing? Or is that SQL Dapper?

Comment: it is pure sql implementation, and I think my answer is wrong, @Ed Punkett ToList should force eager loading. I will delete it. waiting for the  op to respond.

Comment: I see, I know that Sql Dapper `Query` implementation will release the related connection. Would be nice to get clarification.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to build a project here withe similar thing, Ideally SQLConnection goes as singelton.

Comment: if i put inside block using i get error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: post the full exception and stack in question, we will see.

Comment: I connect to remote DB and get records. And regarding this data i looking data in my local Db, in table Surveys.

Comment: One more solution here is to remove Context Dependency from you ServeyManager class. This will avoid having parellal DBClass